# Difference between Model Predictive Control and Rolling Horizon Optimization

Tags: optimization, model-predictive-control

Lately I've been reading numerous papers regarding Energy Hub optimization, and often the authors talk about **rolling horizon** optimization for taking into account uncertainty.

For instance:

- "[A rolling horizon optimization framework for the simultaneous energy supply and demand planning in microgrids](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306261915007230)"
- "[Peer-to-peer energy sharing through a two-stage aggregated battery control in a community Microgrid](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306261918308146)"

To me, this seems similar to the Model Predictive Control approach.

Is there any difference between Rolling Horizon optimization approach and Model Predictive Control approach? Are these two terms interchangeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, effectively the same thing. Also called receding horizon control.

Comment: Thank you for both answering and for your hard work behind YALMIP